# ACCEPT statements in policy DROP

Tags: iptables, debian-wheezy

I'm trying to set up some rules using IPtables under Debian (Wheezy) and have been running in to some problems i think.

The policy of INPUT is set to DROP.
Does this drop everything based on the rules I put into INPUT or is it like a standard ACL-list in some routers, meaning that everything not matched by the statements (if they are set with ACCEPT) will result in a DROP?

Take this as an example:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:ftp-data:ftp
```

Will these ftp-packets drop or will they be accepted and everything else will drop?

I hope I'm not messing it up to much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"meaning that everything not matched by the statements (if they are set with ACCEPT) will result in a DROP?" - correct. It's a default.

Answer (score 0):

From `man iptables`:

```
-j, --jump target
 This specifies the target of the rule; i.e., what to do
 if the packet matches it. The target can be...one of the
 special builtin targets which decide the fate of the
 packet immediately
```

and

```
ACCEPT means to let the packet through.
```

Logging always helps for understanding the flow. Try: `iptables -A INPUT -j LOG`.

If you're particularly trying to set up FTP, have a look at `--state RELATED`.